# RegionDifference - the command does not work as shown in the help - example

Tags: regions

Colleagues, good morning.

Unfortunately, while solving my problem, I ran into a problem that stopped my project completely. RegionDifference command does not work as shown in the help topic.

All bodies transformed into mesh by the DiscretizeRegion.

Details is in the figure bellow, the source code and external stl file are by the link bellow.

RegionUnion - works, RegionDifference doesn't.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Zw-BltM3weUaq7nnf__fVambX4mac2dH?usp=sharing

[image: RegionUnion - works, RegionDifference doesn't]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't add the bugs tag yourself. It will be added if appropriate once the behavior has been confirmed as a bug. Could you provide a simpler example that does not require us to download a file from an external source, and also please post your code as text, rather than pictures, so we can copy into MMA. What behavior did you expect for the last command?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Can you share the non-mesh regions too? You could have a look at the [OpenCascadeLink](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/OpenCascadeLink/tutorial/UsingOpenCascadeLink.html) to get a better/working result.